# Why does Galaxy S5 not find php file used to send email from HTML form?

Tags: php, android, forms, file-io, s5

Galaxy S5 continues to refuse index.html form submission with the following:

This webpage is not found

```
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

// Details

```
No webpage was found for the web address http://metromilwaukee.com/cgc-test/email-credentials.php
```

- index.html form uses action="email-credentials.php"
- The email-credentials.php file is exactly where the path implies.

The form is used to email an attachment. All of my code works fine on an Android tablet, a Kindle and with browsers on Windows desktop. I am at wits end with this Galaxy S5 issue and need help. I have no way to test for iPhone or iPad yet and have no other mobile devices except my Galaxy S5.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
    id="cgc-send-employment-credentials-form"
    name="cgc-send-employment-credentials-form"
    role="form"
    method="post"
    action='email-credentials.php'>
```

The Jasny button is currently active if anybody wants to pound on it at http://metromilwaukee.com/cgc-test/

This is not CORS as all files are in the root folder of the same domain.
How can I code to send email from a Galaxy S5?

Comment: cors would only enter into play if you're doing ajax requests. a form can be loaded from anywhere, and submit to anywhere. and if it was cors, then you'd get a security violation warning, not just "not found"

Comment: What happens if you put `<?php print_r($_POST); die();` at the top of email.credentials.php. It sounds like your web server might be sending a 404 for some reason and the S5 is the only device respecting that.

Comment: I observed vcwvcb submit an instance of the form. I returned here and added print_r($_POST); die(); to email-credentials.php as suggested and get this result...


Array ( [EmploymentApplicantName] => FF Jasny MKE [EmploymentApplicantEmail] => clintongallagher@live.com [EmploymentApplicantUrl] => )


The S5 continues to refuse to find and load the php file. So I ran cURL 

curl -v http://metromilwaukee.com/cgc-test/email-credentials.php

No unsual clues

Comment: Who submitted the form as vcvvcb and which device was used?

Comment: I've settled on using Lima BootStrap FIleStyle however AFIK none of the various jQuery file input stylers are causing the S5 to claim S5 cannot find the PHP file being used to send the email with an attachment.

I delved into PHPMailer and it really functions well.

I still need help debugging and hopefully solving this issue if anybody cares to try submitting a file by banging on the form located at http://metromilwaukee.com/cgc-test/

I am stumped.